# Gcloud crashed (ValueError): Invalid header value

Tags: gcloud, ddl, google-cloud-spanner

I used the following DDL command to create a table in gcloud spanner database named "messages" in the "guestbook" spanner instance

```
gcloud spanner databases ddl update messages \
  --instance=guestbook --ddl="$(<~/guestbook-service/db/spanner.ddl)"
```

spanner.ddl contains the following

```
CREATE TABLE guestbook_message (
    id STRING(36) NOT NULL,
    name STRING(255) NOT NULL,
    image_uri STRING(255),
    message STRING(255)
) PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

But I get the following error.

> ERROR: gcloud crashed (ValueError): Invalid header value
> b'/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py spanner databases ddl
> update messages --instance=guestbook --d dl=CREATE TABLE
> guestbook_message (\n    id STRING(36) NOT NULL,\n    name STRING(255)
> NOT NULL,\n    image_uri STRING(255),\n    message STRING(255)\n)
> PRIMARY KEY (id );'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This gcloud command is not accepting ddl statements with new line character `\n`.

It is enough to change `spanner.ddl` to:

```
CREATE TABLE guestbook_message (id STRING(36) NOT NULL,name STRING(255) NOT NULL,image_uri STRING(255),message STRING(255)) PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

If all is in one line, without those `\n` it works fine.